# Not Able to render the Scafffold view properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to render the below Scaffold to the screen which has StreamBuilder for retrieving documents from firestore database, bottom textfield with button,
but it is giving me runtime error of this. How should I resolve this error in flutter?

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Vertical
>   viewport was given unbounded height.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("COMMENTS", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: query.snapshots(),
              builder: (context,snapshot){
                //String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['postContent'];

                if (!snapshot.hasData){
                  return Text("Loading");
                }

                return ListView.builder(

                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['postContent'];
                      String postId = snapshot.data.documents[index]["post_id"];
                      return CardItem(itemTitle:itemTitle, postid: postId,);

                    });
              },
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: BottomAppBar(
                elevation: 10,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: 100,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                      ),

                      Flexible(
                        child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "Write your message...",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
                            ),
                          ),
                          maxLines: null,
                        ),
                      ),

                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.mic,
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){},
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),


      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have list view under a column without any constraints to the list view. If you wrap the list view in a container and give it a fixed height it will fix the issue.

In your case, you should wrap the streambuilder in expanded widget.

This will remove the error. The error basically says, list view without a fixed a height takes up height of infinity.

Comment: Thank You, I am learning flutter it's a good to go thing now.